# Send a form array to PHP using AJAX as a POST array

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Guys I am looking for a way to send my html form array to the php script to execute as an array.I tried several methods but nothing worked for me.Please suggest me a method to do it.My php array works well with normal submit but with ajax it says

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() in
>   C:\wamp\www\submit_order.php on line
>   42

My HTML form code-

```
 <input disabled="disabled" class="input_text" onkeyup="JAVASCRIPT:check_row();" name="qty[]" type="text" id="qty_field1" size="6">
```

My current ajax send params-

```
var params="qty="+document.table_form.elements["qty[]"]";
```

My PHP array fetch -

```
  foreach($_POST['qty'] as $value){
        if($index<=$rows){
        $clean_value=mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        $clean_value=stripcslashes($clean_value);
        $product_data[$index][3]=$clean_value;
        $index=$index+1;
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using `POST` in your AJAX?

Comment: @Kyle
Yes I use POST Kyle

@KilZone I'll accept some.I didn't know that function.:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

I am a bonehead--you are not using jQuery.  Here is some coee which iterates the inputs in a form looking for elements named `qty[]` http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/WQjQM/6/

**END EDIT**

*Original (jQuery) Answer Below*

If I have 3 inputs named `qty[]` with values `a`, `b`, `c`

**Both:**

```
var params = $.param( $( '[name="qty\[\]"]' ) );
```

*(demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/WQjQM/1/ )*

**and:**

```
var params = $( '[name="qty\[\]"]' ).serialize();
```

*(demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/WQjQM/ )*

**give me:**

```
qty%5B%5D=a&qty%5B%5D=b&qty%5B%5D=c
```

This should be correct for you.

Comment: @JAAulde
Thank you for your response but I have more than 40 values with qty[].So do you have some other way to do this.

Comment: @Ceylo I fail to see why it makes a difference...have you tried it? Does it work? Is it performing ok?

Comment: @JAAulde sorry my mistake.I am new to jquery friend.Can you explain me what is above give me: string.How should I send it to php.How php get this data?.Thanx

Comment: @Ceylo no problem.  Send it the same way you already are, I imagine: `$.ajax( { url: '/yourPage.php', type: 'POST', data: params } );`

Comment: @JAAulde I am using a javascript based ajax request.Can I use above with that or should I have to use a jQuery based ajax?.

Comment: Oh, dude, I am sooooo sorry. Based on the first answer submitted, and having seen the `$` in your PHP code block, I totally effed up and thought you were using jQuery. I've misled you, let me reformulate...

Comment: @Ceylo - edited answer posted, I hope it helps. At the end of my code `param_string` holds what `params` was holding in your original posted code.

Comment: No problem, sorry for the confusion on my end which made it take so long!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ as a solution of how to send off the form values. It should work with arrays (I think)

Comment: Or found this which could help if you do not wish to use jQuery: http://ra-ajax.org/how-to-create-an-ajax-library-part-6-serializing-your-forms