# How do I pass my form arrays to my PHP script within my function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, serialization

How do I pass my form arrays to my PHP script? My php script will be serializing the data ready to be input into mysql.

Form input WHITHOUT the [] will happily pass through one value to my php. but i need to pass through and array so was thinking using the [] and then serializing on my php.

```
var fcl_form_data = {
index: window.localStorage.getItem("fcl_form_data:index"),
$table: document.getElementById("fcl_form_data-table"),
$form: document.getElementById("fcl_form_data-form"),
$button_save: document.getElementById("fcl_form_data-op-save"),
$button_discard: document.getElementById("fcl_form_data-op-discard"),
init:
function() {
        // initialize storage index
        if (!fcl_form_data.index) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("fcl_form_data:index", fcl_form_data.index = 1);
        }

    // initialize form
    fcl_form_data.$form.reset();

    fcl_form_data.$form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    var entry = {
    id: parseInt(this.id_entry.value),
    client_number:this.client_number.value,
    client_name:this.client_name.value,


    // HERE Just these middle fields are arrays []

    service:this.service.value,
    size:this.size.value,
    volume:this.volume.value,
    deliver_point:this.deliver_point.value,
    port_orgin:this.port_orgin.value,
    a_port_orgin:this.a_port_orgin.value,
    road_freight:this.road_freight.value,
    terms:this.terms.value,
    competitor:this.competitor.value,
    freight_speed:this.freight_speed.value,
    report_comments:this.report_comments.value,

    // HERE 

    company_stage:this.company_stage.value,
    client_user_name:this.client_user_name.value,
    client_user_name_status:this.client_user_name_status.value,
    client_user_name_kids:this.client_user_name_kids.value,
    client_user_name_hobbies:this.client_user_name_hobbies.value,
    client_user_comments:this.client_user_comments.value
    };

    if (entry.id == 0) { // add
    fcl_form_data.storeAdd(entry);
    // Adds data to table when pressed save - like a temp table above
    fcl_form_data.tableAdd(entry);
    }
    else { // edit
    fcl_form_data.storeEdit(entry);
    fcl_form_data.tableEdit(entry);
    }
    this.reset();
    this.id_entry.value = 0;
    event.preventDefault();
    },
    true);
```

Form inputs are like this -

```
<input type="text" name="deliver_point[]" placeholder="Deliver Point">
```

my Ajax -

```
    databaseAdd: function(entry) {

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "//cms/by/m_upload.php",
  data: entry ,
  success: function(v) {alert("okay");},
  failure: function(v) {alert("fail");},
  dataType: JSON
});
```

},

MY PHP -

```
$client_number = $_POST['client_number'];
$client_name = $_POST['client_name'];

$service =serialize ($_POST['service']);
$size =serialize ($_POST['size']);
$volume =serialize ($_POST['volume']);
$deliver_point =serialize ($_POST['deliver_point']);
$port_orgin =serialize ($_POST['port_orgin']);
$a_port_orgin =serialize ($_POST['road_freight']);
$terms =serialize ($_POST['terms']);
$competitor =serialize ($_POST['competitor']);
$freight_speed =serialize ($_POST['freight_speed']);
$report_comments =serialize ($_POST['report_comments']);

$company_stage = $_POST['company_stage'];
$meeting_rating = $_POST['meeting_rating'];
$client_user_name = $_POST['client_user_name'];
$client_user_status = $_POST['client_user_status'];
$client_user_kids = $_POST['client_user_kids'];
$client_user_hobbies = $_POST['client_user_hobbies'];
$client_user_comments = $_POST['client_user_comments'];


$query="INSERT INTO l_reports (client_number,client_name,service,size,volume,deliver_point,port_orgin,a_port_orgin,road_freight,terms,competitor,freight_speed,report_comments,company_stage,meeting_rating,client_user_name,client_user_status,client_user_kids,client_user_hobbies,client_user_comments)

VALUES ('".$client_number."', '".$client_name."', '".$service."', '".$size."', '".$volume."', '".$deliver_point."', '".$port_orgin."', '".$a_port_orgin."', '".$road_freight."', '".$terms."', '".$competitor."', '".$freight_speed."', '".$report_comments."', '".$company_stage."', '".$meeting_rating."', '".$client_user_name."', '".$client_user_status."', '".$client_user_kids."', '".$client_user_hobbies."', '".$client_user_comments."');";

$result = $dbLink->query($query);
```

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send a form array to PHP using AJAX as a POST array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428121/send-a-form-array-to-php-using-ajax-as-a-post-array)

Comment: That`s not helped me sorry @Daenu

Comment: The name of the input is not able to define the input type, having it as `name[]` will not change anything, but why not use a JS array object `var postObj = {nam1:val1, nam2:val2};` etc and pass that directly back to php ? Then deserializing ? Also what is being returned // received by your `/cms/by/m_upload.php` ?

Comment: @Pogrindis Iv just added my PHP script for you to have a look at. I want the array to be passed to it and then serialize + inserted into my database serialize.

Comment: @elliestone have you read into the json php documentation yet  : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php ? The `POST[x]` vars are already in JSON format, so you need to parse them back to objects using `json_decode`.

Comment: Ill have a read into it now, but where would I use the json_decode in my code @Pogrindis Thanks for the help btw

Comment: @elliestone with the current way you have written your php, the `$_POST` vars should be as `$client_number = json_decode($_POST['client_number']);` This is because the `$_POST` is ready, just needs to be decoded.

Comment: @elliestone I have added an Example to explain : http://ideone.com/eKeosi

Comment: @Pogrindis Before it goes to my php page its populated into a HTML table for personal review, with a links  next to it saying Save to database / edit / delete. It wont show in the table therefore I can press Save to database.  Heres the full code in a fiddle .... https://jsfiddle.net/n4naktrx/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91730/discussion-between-ellie-stone-and-pogrindis).

Comment: @Pogrindis Iv lost 1 rep so can talk to chat.....

Answer (score 1):

A small refactoring of your code would make life a lot easier for you.

For example, the ajax request which you are sending, you could make it more effiecient for the server side php by sending an object like this.

```
var postObjct = {
    data: entry
};
```

Then when you send it to the php like so :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "//cms/by/m_upload.php",
  data: postObjct ,
  success: function(v) {alert("okay");},
  failure: function(v) {alert("fail");},
  dataType: JSON
});
```

You only have 1 `json_decode` to work with on the php :

```
//php
$postedObject = json_decode($_POST['data']);
//This POST['data'] actually contains everything in your javascript 'entry' object.
```

Now with this `php` object you can work with the values in this way :

```
//php
$client_number = $postedObject->{"client_number"};
//Or — TODO: Will need to test the structure
$client_number = $postedObject["entry"]["client_number"];
```

Of course you should do checks for nulls etc, but this will make your life a little easier!